# CSS Select Elements Attribute or Attribute with nth-of-type

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-selectors

I wish to select all inputs that have either the `required` attribute or as `type='submit'` and then iterate through them with nth-of-type.

Something like: `(input[required]|[type='submit']):nth-of-type(1)`

Example:

4 required inputs, then two non-required, and then submit.

The first that matches (required or submit) is green, the second blue, third yellow, fourth orange, fifth red etc.

Comment: "I wish to select all inputs" Any reason you have that :nth-child(1) there?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, cause i'm selecting them all, and then giving each a different color.

Answer (score 3):

Although the pipe (`|`) symbol means "OR" in several programming languages (although it's usually `||`) and in [W3C specification syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#component-combinators), it doesn't have that meaning in CSS.

["OR" can be expressed by a comma in CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```css
input[required],
input[type="submit"]{
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="radio"><br>
<input type="checkbox" required><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: How would I use this though with nth-child to give each element a different color?

Comment: So nth-of-type is what I'd want?
I currently have no code other than the tiny snippet I've added.

Comment: Completely changing a question after answers have been provided is not very good practice. There was nothing about loops, iterations or `nth-of-type` in the original question. The only reference to `nth-child` was minor and unreferenced.

Comment: I knew something was up with that :nth-child().